# NodeJS appears to run an exported function when it compiles--why?

Tags: node.js, compilation, node-modules

I'm trying to reference a function from my `alchemy/broker_communication/tradeking.js` module in another module `alchemy/scheduler/scheduler.js`

However, well before the code in `scheduler` gets run, the function I'm trying to export from `tradeking.js` is being run. I have no idea why; I added a stack trace to the function in tradeking and it looks like Node's compiler is invoking it for some reason, but a lot of frustrated googling has not found me the answer to this particular strangeness.

These are the modules that should be relevant:

index.js

```
module.exports = 
{
  config: require('./config/config.js'),
  analysis_runner: require('./analysis_runner/analysis_runner_prototype.js'),
  data_feed: require('./data_feed/iex.js'),
  broker: require('./broker_communication/tradeking.js')
}
```

scheduler/scheduler.js

```
var routes = require('../index.js');
var data_feed = routes.data_feed;
var analysis_runner = routes.analysis_runner;
var broker = routes.broker;

let results = data_feed.fetch('AAPL', '20190327');
results.then(data => analysis_runner.analyze(data));

broker.printAccountData();
```

broker_communication/tradeking.js

```
var oauth = require('oauth');
var routes = require('../index.js');
var config = require('../config/config.js');

module.exports =
{
  printAccountData: function() 
  {
    console.log("Config is " + config);
    console.log(new Error().stack);
    tradekingConsumer.get(config.api_url + '/accounts.json', config.access_token, config.access_secret, function (err, data, res) {
      if (!data == null) {
        acctData = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('accttDataccttData: ' + JSON.stringify(acctData.response));
      }
    });
  }
}

var tradekingConsumer = new oauth.OAuth
(
  "https://developers.tradeking.com/oauth/request_token",
  "https://developers.tradeking.com/oauth/access_token",
  config.consumer_key,
  config.consumer_secret,
  "-1.0",
  null,
  "HMAC-SHA1"
);
```

You can also just see the full project at https://gitlab.com/dalseides/alchemy (although to test the broker communication portion you would need an Ally Invest account + API credentials).

Full program output:

> alchemy 厶 node scheduler/scheduler.js
>   Config is [object Object] Error
>       at Object.printAccountData (/code/alchemy/broker_communication/tradeking.js:10:17)
>
> ```
> at Object.<anonymous> (/code/alchemy/scheduler/scheduler.js:9:8)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
> at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11 Average: 188.755                S Mv Avg: 188.8498              L Mv Avg: 188.81733333333332
> ```
>
> shortIsHigh: true
>   --- BUYBUYBUY --- Average: 188.48         S Mv Avg: 188.79479999999998            L Mv Avg: 188.82755555555553            shortIsHigh: false
>
> --- SELLSELLSELL --- Average: 188.666                S Mv Avg: 188.80620000000002            L Mv Avg: 188.7992666666667             shortIsHigh: true
>   --- BUYBUYBUY --- Average: 188.497                S Mv Avg: 188.76                L Mv Avg: 188.8768965517242             shortIsHigh: false
>
> --- SELLSELLSELL --- Average: 188.865                S Mv Avg: 188.7616              L Mv Avg: 188.74286666666669            shortIsHigh: true
>   --- BUYBUYBUY --- Average: 188.867                S Mv Avg: 189.17379999999997            L Mv Avg: 189.25986666666668            shortIsHigh: false
>   --- SELLSELLSELL --- Average: 189.03         S Mv Avg: 188.9752              L Mv Avg: 188.96590000000003            shortIsHigh: true
>
> --- BUYBUYBUY --- Average: 188.776                S Mv Avg: 188.895               L Mv Avg: 188.89863333333335            shortIsHigh: false
>
> --- SELLSELLSELL --- Average: 188.927                S Mv Avg: 188.8658              L Mv Avg: 188.85473333333337            shortIsHigh: true
>   --- BUYBUYBUY --- Average: 188.517                S Mv Avg: 188.7594              L Mv Avg: 188.7894              shortIsHigh: false
>
> --- SELLSELLSELL --- Average: 187.388                S Mv Avg: 187.12439999999998            L Mv Avg: 187.07276666666667            shortIsHigh: true
>   --- BUYBUYBUY --- Average: 188.085                S Mv Avg: 188.2184              L Mv Avg: 188.23606666666672            shortIsHigh: false
>
> --- SELLSELLSELL --- Average: 188.304                S Mv Avg: 188.2522              L Mv Avg: 188.24159999999998            shortIsHigh: true
>   --- BUYBUYBUY --- Average: 188.156                S Mv Avg: 188.2298              L Mv Avg: 188.23733333333334            shortIsHigh: false
>
> --- SELLSELLSELL --- Average: 188.514                S Mv Avg: 188.1266              L Mv Avg: 188.0391              shortIsHigh: true
>   --- BUYBUYBUY --- Average: 188.83         S Mv Avg: 188.9246              L Mv Avg: 188.96199999999996            shortIsHigh: false
>
> --- SELLSELLSELL --- Average: 189.026                S Mv Avg: 188.9622              L Mv Avg: 188.9615333333333             shortIsHigh: true
>   --- BUYBUYBUY --- Average: 188.775                S Mv Avg: 188.93040000000002            L Mv Avg: 188.97613333333337            shortIsHigh: false
>   --- SELLSELLSELL --- Average: 188.419                S Mv Avg: 188.3324              L Mv Avg: 188.31433333333334            shortIsHigh: true
>   --- BUYBUYBUY --- Average: 188.438                S Mv Avg: 188.5306              L Mv Avg: 188.54593333333332            shortIsHigh: false
>
> --- SELLSELLSELL --- TOTALPROFITGUYS: -0.4730000000000132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.<anonymous> (/code/alchemy/scheduler/scheduler.js:9:8)`
Looks to me like it is running from scheduler.

The call before it is async
`let results = data_feed.fetch('AAPL', '20190327');
results.then(data => analysis_runner.analyze(data));`

Are you sure it shouldnt be called after that? I.E.
`let results = data_feed.fetch('AAPL', '20190327')
   .then(data => analysis_runner.analyze(data))
   .then(() => broker.printAccountData())`